# Multi Custom picklist fields with single source values

Tags: configuration

I have two custom objects: `CO1__c` and `CO2__c`. I also have two custom picklist fields: `CO1__c.foo__c` and `CO2__c.foo__c`.

Is there any ways that field `foo__c` in both have same possible Picklist Values ?
( currently, I don't want to copy and paste those values to two places )

Comment: You may think it's just two places, but just wait until you start adding different record types to those objects.

Comment: Apart from the obvious, why don't you want to copy the values across?  Is there an issue with them becoming out of sync, or some other issues that has popped up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options..

Either wait for Salesforce to implement this most popular age old [Universal Picklist Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrfBAAS)

This idea is currently marked as Beta / Pilot so you might contact SF to get it activated for your org if possible

or

Use one of the appexchange apps that can simulate universal/global picklist & sync multiple picklist fields

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000pvmXEAQ